# Estou com problema para acessar o servidor MySql

Tags: mysql

Estou usando o HeidiSQL para conectar aos meus servidores MySql. Nas maquinas no qual eu configurei eu consigo conectar sem problemas para o servidor Mysql. Mas no caso dessa que não fui eu que configurei está dando o problema de:

```
Access denied for user 'sge'@'10.70.9.106' (using password: NO)
```

Sendo que eu já forneci e já alterei a senha e tentei deletar e recriar o usuário e mesmo assim da o mesmo erro. Não tenho ideia do que pode ser e não encontro em fóruns. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Você diz: " já forneci e já alterei a senha". Mas o usuário ali não usou senha alguma. `(using password: NO)`  O usuário (sge), tem senha?

Comment: Tem senha sim, eu forneci mas ele fica informando que eu não botei senha. Já tentei usar em outros programas e conectar via PHP mas da o mesmo erro.

Comment: Tem senha, mas como você informou que não foi você quem configurou. Então a pessoa ao criar uma conta no HeidiSQL(Ela usa esse tb?), lá no Session manager, ela n definiu senha. O esquema de conexão está salva, mas está sem a senha. A pessoa esquece. Eu acho melhor você ir no local e configurar. Pq n tem como vc saber.